# How can I find the intersection of two sets and how can I sample elements from this intersection?

Tags: equation-solving, intersection

I've solved a non-linear system of equations and the numerical solution I obtained was the following:

```
  {{x -> 
     ConditionalExpression[0.125 (-5. - 8. y + 48. z), 
       (-24.0367 <= y <= 0.373823 
         && 
           Root[1.4184*10^9 - 1.14866*10^9 y + 3.59484*10^8 y^2 - 
             1.83744*10^8 y^3 + 
             5.568*10^7 y^4 + (-1.65159*10^10 - 5.23081*10^9 y - 
             6.91386*10^9 y^2 - 9.78854*10^8 y^3 - 
             6.5257*10^8 y^4) #1 + (-9.28089*10^9 - 9.79188*10^8 y - 
             1.24545*10^9 y^2 + 1.60358*10^8 y^3 + 
             1.06906*10^8 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.31117*10^8 + 
             3.12699*10^8 y + 4.16932*10^8 y^2) #1^3 + 
              4.26553*10^8 #1^4 &, 1]
           <= z <= 
           Root[1.77292*10^11 - 1.43567*10^11 y + 4.49381*10^10 y^2 - 
               2.29657*10^10 y^3 + 
               6.96*10^9 y^4 + (-2.06444*10^12 - 6.53839*10^11 y - 
               8.64219*10^11 y^2 - 1.22355*10^11 y^3 - 
               8.15703*10^10 y^4) #1 + (-1.1601*10^12 - 
               1.22397*10^11 y - 1.55679*10^11 y^2 + 
               2.00448*10^10 y^3 + 
               1.33632*10^10 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.88882*10^10 + 
               3.90874*10^10 y + 5.21165*10^10 y^2) #1^3 + 
               5.33192*10^10 #1^4 &, 2]) 
         || 
           (Root[1.77292*10^11 - 1.43567*10^11 y + 4.49381*10^10 y^2 - 
              2.29657*10^10 y^3 + 
              6.96*10^9 y^4 + (-2.06444*10^12 - 6.53839*10^11 y - 
              8.64219*10^11 y^2 - 1.22355*10^11 y^3 - 
              8.15703*10^10 y^4) #1 + (-1.1601*10^12 - 
              1.22397*10^11 y - 1.55679*10^11 y^2 + 
              2.00448*10^10 y^3 + 
              1.33632*10^10 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.88882*10^10 + 
              3.90874*10^10 y + 5.21165*10^10 y^2) #1^3 + 
              5.33192*10^10 #1^4 &, 1]
            <= z <= 
            Root[1.77292*10^11 - 1.43567*10^11 y + 4.49381*10^10 y^2 - 
              2.29657*10^10 y^3 + 
              6.96*10^9 y^4 + (-2.06444*10^12 - 6.53839*10^11 y - 
              8.64219*10^11 y^2 - 1.22355*10^11 y^3 - 
              8.15703*10^10 y^4) #1 + (-1.1601*10^12 - 
              1.22397*10^11 y - 1.55679*10^11 y^2 + 
              2.00448*10^10 y^3 + 
              1.33632*10^10 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.88882*10^10 + 
              3.90874*10^10 y + 5.21165*10^10 y^2) #1^3 + 
              5.33192*10^10 #1^4 &, 2] 
            && 
            y > 0.373823) 
         || 
           (Root[1.77292*10^11 - 1.43567*10^11 y + 4.49381*10^10 y^2 - 
              2.29657*10^10 y^3 + 
              6.96*10^9 y^4 + (-2.06444*10^12 - 6.53839*10^11 y - 
              8.64219*10^11 y^2 - 1.22355*10^11 y^3 - 
              8.15703*10^10 y^4) #1 + (-1.1601*10^12 - 
              1.22397*10^11 y - 1.55679*10^11 y^2 + 
              2.00448*10^10 y^3 + 
              1.33632*10^10 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.88882*10^10 + 
              3.90874*10^10 y + 5.21165*10^10 y^2) #1^3 + 
              5.33192*10^10 #1^4 &, 1] <= z <= 
            Root[1.77292*10^11 - 1.43567*10^11 y + 4.49381*10^10 y^2 - 
              2.29657*10^10 y^3 + 
              6.96*10^9 y^4 + (-2.06444*10^12 - 6.53839*10^11 y - 
              8.64219*10^11 y^2 - 1.22355*10^11 y^3 - 
              8.15703*10^10 y^4) #1 + (-1.1601*10^12 - 
              1.22397*10^11 y - 1.55679*10^11 y^2 + 
              2.00448*10^10 y^3 + 
              1.33632*10^10 y^4) #1^2 + (-2.88882*10^10 + 
              3.90874*10^10 y + 5.21165*10^10 y^2) #1^3 + 
              5.33192*10^10 #1^4 &, 2] 
            &&
            y < -24.0367)]}}
```

How can I find the intersection of two sets and how can I sample elements from this intersection?

To be honest, I can't even figure out what elements belong to the set I obtained as the solution to my system of equations. But that's OK, because all I'm interested in is finding its intersection with the set

```
{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1} - {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 0.001}.
```

Edit 3: The set I mean above is

`{0.001 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}`

I'd also like to sample elements from this intersection in case it is non-empty. Is it possible to do such things with Mathematica?

Edit 1: Here follows the code that gave me that solution:

Edit 2: I changed the function k

```
k = (((6 - x)^2 - (y)^2)*z + 0.5*(6^2 - (6 - x)^2)*10 + 
 0.5*10*y^2)/(2*z*(6 - x - y) + x*10 + y*10)

Ixx = 1/3*(10*((6 - (k))^3 - (6 - x - (k))^3) + 
    2*z*((6 - x - (k))^3 - (-(k) + y)^3) + 
    10*((-(k) + y)^3 - (-(k))^3))

Q1 = -(k)*(y*10 + 2*((6 - x) - (k))*z) + 0.5*10*(6^2 - (6 - x)^2) + 
  z*((6 - x)^2 - (k)^2)

Q2 = (k)*(y*10 + 2*((k) - y)*z) + 0.5*10*y^2 - z*((k)^2 - (y)^2)
NSolve[{290*10*Ixx >= 2.4*Q1, 580*Ixx >= 24*6/2, 
  60*(2*6*(z - x - y) + x*10 + y*10)*8*10 + 2*500*12 == 
   60*(10*3)*1*10}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

Comment: show you initial code of before solution! to make our life easier !

Comment: @Alrubaie sure thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can avoid the conditional expression altogether with the following approach.  First, your expressions

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

k = (6^2*z + 0.5*(6 - x)*10 + 0.5*10*y^2)/(2*6*(z - x - y) + x*10 + 
     y*10);

Ixx = 1/3*(10*((6 - (k))^3 - (6 - x - (k))^3) + 
     2*z*((6 - x - (k))^3 - (-(k) + y)^3) + 
     10*((-(k) + y)^3 - (-(k))^3));

Q1 = -(k)*(y*10 + 2*((6 - x) - (k))*z) + 0.5*10*(6^2 - (6 - x)^2) + 
   z*((6 - x)^2 - (k)^2);

Q2 = (k)*(y*10 + 2*((k) - y)*z) + 0.5*10*y^2 - z*((k)^2 - (y)^2);
```

Now, instead of using `NSolve` we can write the two inequalities and the one equation as

```
c1 = 290*10*Ixx >= 2.4*Q1;
c2 = 580*Ixx >= 24*6/2;

eqn = 60*(2*6*(z - x - y) + x*10 + y*10)*8*10 + 2*500*12 == 
   60*(10*3)*1*10;
```

We can obtain a value, zeta, for `z` using `Solve`, as

```
ζ = z /. First@Solve[eqn, z]
```

We can now define a region in the (x,y)-plane that satisfies our two inequality constraints, like this

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[ c1 && c2 /. z->ζ,
       {{x,-10,50},{y,-10,10}}];
Plot3D[ζ, {x, y} ∈ r1]
```

[image]

The result above is a visualization of the region of $z=\zeta$ plane that satisfies the inequalities and the equation that had been in the `NSolve` expression.

We have two more constraints that we can use.  If we only want to consider solutions between the two spheres, we can write these expressions

```
c3 = {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
c4 = {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1/Sqrt[1000]];

r2 = ImplicitRegion[c1 && c2 && c3 /. z -> ζ,
       {{x, -10, 50}, {y, -10, 10}}];
Plot3D[{ζ, Sqrt[1/1000 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, y} ∈ r2]
```

That gives us a visualization of the region in the solution between the two spheres and of the smaller sphere.
[image]

Note that the second region, $r_2$, does not explicitly include `&& Not[c4]` in its constraints.  We can check the minimum $z$ value for the $(x,y)$ points in $r_2$ with

```
Minimize[{ζ, {x, y} ∈ r2}, {x, y}]
(*  {0.0427734, {x -> -0.866208, y -> 0.497849}}  *)
```

This tell us that the region $z=\zeta$ does not intersect the ball $c_4$ for $(x,y)\in r_2$.

Finally, if we want to sample the points in $r_2$, we can use this:

```
nSample = 10;
{x, y, ζ} /. FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ r2, {x, y}, nSample]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, really appreciate it! Would you know how could I restrict the solution set to values of x,y,z>0?

Comment: We can restrict the sampling region to positive values of x, y, z by modifying the intervals in the `ImplicitRegion` statement that defines the region.

Comment: I just realized something, when I said I was only interested in the solutions satisfying {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1} - {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 0.001}, I meant to say those that are elements of the set {0.001 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}. 

I tried correcting that on your code  by defining c4 as:

c4 = {x, y, z} \[NotElement]  Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 0.001];

And redefining c2 as:

r2 = ImplicitRegion[
   c1 && c2 && c3 && c4 /. 
    z -> \[Zeta], {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];

But, unfortunately, I didn't get any solutions.